# How can you get a list of groups from a gmail user?

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-groups

I am building a web app that utilizes groups, facebook groups, email list groups etc. .
However, I realized google doesn't offer API access to groups the way facebook does(I was surprised really).
I just want read access, and maybe the ability to send an email to a gmail user's group of choice.
Any workarounds?
How can you get a list of groups from a gmail user?
How can i post to the said user's group(s)

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html#retrieving_groups_without_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean if there is no API, you're not getting access...